# Declaring a PHP array with strings written on multiple lines

Tags: php, arrays, string

PHP allows to declare a string on multiple lines as following:

```
$s = <<<EOS
    Hello
    World!
EOS;
```

Is is possible to use that notation to declare an array of strings? I'd like to write a code such as the following one (that is of course not working):

```
$data = array(<<<EOS
    Hello
    World!
EOS;, 
<<<EOS
    Hello
    Me!
EOS;);
```

Comment: Delete `;` after `EOS` from your array

Comment: Oh yes, it's also working by removing all the ; after the EOS! Thanks!

Comment: @pes502 I get errors and/or the wrong output without additional modification as shown in my answer.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I don't see any errors, but the output is bugged. So you really need to add coma and `);` (array ending) to the separate lines. +1 for you

Comment: I am testing at http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/ with PHP 7.0.5 and closing the array on the same line as the closing EOS, like this `EOS);`, produces a parse error.

Comment: You can but I wouldn't, if anything I would store the strings in variables and place those variables in your array for readabilities sake. I imagine you may come back to this piece of code later on and wonder what the hell it's doing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Certainly you can:

```
<?php
$a = array(<<<EOS
    foo
    bar!
EOS
, // comma here is important
<<<EOS
    bar
    foo!
EOS
); // closing the array on a separate line is important

print_r($a);
```

See Example #3 at http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

---

This works too by the way:

```
<?php
$a = array(
    'foo
    bar!',
    'bar
    foo!'
);

print_r($a);
```

Answer (score 0):

I use templates for long text:

```
     $data = array(file_get_contents('file1.txt'),  
file_get_contents('file2.txt')
    );



 print_r($data);exit;
```

file1.txt content

"sample line1"

file2.txt content

"sample line2
end of line

"